# How to mark the packet with a specific IP address using iptables command?

Tags: ip, firewall

We can mark all the tcp packet while forwarding them using the following :

`iptables -A FORWARD -t mangle -p tcp -j MARK --set-mark 1`

Is there any way to mark the packets for a particular IP address?

Comment: What do you mean to mark the packets with a specific IP address ? The IP that is the source of the packet? Or the destination? or to redirect the packets to a specific IP address ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the destination is 192.168.1.1:

```
iptables -A FORWARD -t mangle -d 192.168.1.1/24 -j MARK --set-mark 1
```

Comment: And for the source with `-s` right?

Comment: yes, if the source is 192.168.1.1

Comment: iptables -A FORWARD -t mangle -s 192.168.1.1/24 -j MARK --set-mark 1

Comment: How to mark all the packets for a particular website? Instead of IP address I used website name. But only one particular server is added to the mangle table, what is the website has multiple servers? Like `youtube.com` or `facebook.com` ?

Comment: that is not _directly_ achievable with iptables.  I would suggest opening another question on that topic.